# Using output of awk to run command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am brand new to shell scripting and cannot seem to figure out this seemingly simple task. I have a text file (ciphers.txt) with about 250 lines, and I would like to use the first column of each line as an argument in a command. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

the command is:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port -cipher argument
```

It works fine when I do one at a time but I do not really want to run the same command 250+ times. Here is my script so far:

```
awk '{command = "openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher > results.txt"
print $0 | command}' ciphers.txt
```

I keep getting an error so I am pretty sure I have a syntax error somewhere. Is the output of awk being appended after -cipher?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use `system` from within awk:

```
awk '{ system("openssl s_client -connect host:port -cipher " $1) }' ciphers.txt
```

Answer (score 24):

The `xargs` command is specifically for that use case.

```
awk '{print $0}' <ciphers.txt | xargs -I{} openssl s_client -connect host:port -cipher {} >>results.txt
```

This version is a bit longer for the example case because `awk` was already being used to parse out `$0`.  However, `xargs` comes in handy when you already have a list of things to use and are not running something that can execute a subshell.  For example, `awk` could be used below to execute the `mv` but `xargs` is a lot simpler.

```
ls -1 *.txt | xargs -I{} mv "{}" "{}.$(date '+%y%m%d')"
```

The above command renames each text file in the current directory to a date-stamped backup. The equivalent in `awk` requires making a variable out of the results of the `date` command, passing that into `awk`, and then constructing and executing the command.

The `xargs` command can also accumulate multiple parameters onto a single line which is helpful if the input has multiple columns, or when a single record is split into recurring groups in the input file.

For more on all the ways to use it, have a look at ["xargs" All-IN-One Tutorial Guide](http://www.unixmantra.com/2013/12/xargs-all-in-one-tutorial-guide.html) over at UNIX Mantra.

Comment: I would recommend changing to `find *.txt -print0 | xargs -0`

Answer (score 16):

there are quite a few things wrong with your command. For one you want to use the first column. That's referred to as $1 in awk and not $0 (which would be the whole line). Second, you forgot a semicolon at the end of your definition of command.

To actually run the command you can either use system() or a pipe (the latter only makes sense if the command can read from stdin, which openssl in your case won't, I think).
The easiest would be something like

```
awk '{cmd="openssl s_client -connect host:port -cipher" $1; system(cmd)}' results.txt
```

Note, that this will only return the exit status. If you need to capture stdout, you will have to pipe the command through getline.

Andreas

PS: Posting the actual error you got, would have helped.